# фильтр для строк, как удалить слово

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая определяет есть ли запрещенное слово в тексте, вопрос стоит в том как удалить\заменить это слово целиком?

Пример:
`test('Nickname somesite.com')`
на выходе должен получиться `Nickname •`

```js
function test(value) {
  const text = value.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase()
  const bad_words = [".ru", ".com",".xyz", ".io", ".tk", ".me"]
  let bad_word = false

  for (let i = 0; i < bad_words.length; i++) {
    if (text.indexOf(bad_words[i]) > -1) {
      bad_word = true
      // тут соответсвенно должна быть функция удаления запрещенного слова
      break
    }
  }
  return bad_word // если true значит текст содержит запрещенное слово которое нужно удалить
}
```

Comment: https://javascript.ru/string/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы удалить или заменить слово в строке, можно использовать метод **split**. Этим методом вы разделяете старку на массив: указав в качестве разделителе "запрещенное слово". После чего, методом **join** получены массив можно преобразовать обратно в старку, заменив разделитель участков (,) на новое слово.

Если есть необходимость выполнить проверку большого числа запрещенных слов в текст, то можно сформировать *объект* в котором ключом будит запрещенное слово, а значением ключа замещаемое слово. После чего такой *блок (объект)* запустить на цикле **FOR IN** и на каждом витке перезаписывать старку с внесёнными правками.

```js
var string = "Есть функция которая определяет есть ли запрещенное слово в тексте, вопрос стоит в том как удалить\заменить это слово целиком? Пример: test('Nickname somesite.com') на выходе должен получиться Nickname •"

var cenzrBlock = {
 "Nickname": "Вася"
 ,".com": ""
 ,"somesite": "*"
}

function reString(_string, _filter){
for(let key_ in _filter){
 _string = _string.split(key_).join(_filter[key_])
}
return _string
}

string = reString(string, cenzrBlock)
console.log(string)
```

Если нужно найти запрещённые слова с вхождением в них определённого корня, приставки или окончания. В током случаи также можно использовать метод **split**, но сначала для разделение текста на *слова по пробелу*, после чего в методе циклом **FOR** отправить каждое слово в метод, где оно разделиться по вхождению в нём набора символов, определяющего его как запрещённое и замене токового на альтернативной слово ...

```js
var string = "Есть функция которая определяет есть ли запрещенное слово в тексте, вопрос стоит в том как удалить\заменить это слово целиком? Пример: test('Nickname somesite.com') на выходе должен получиться Nickname •"

var cenzrBlock = {
 "Nickname": "Вася"
 ,".com": "*"
}

function reWord(_word, _filter){
 for(let key_ in _filter){  
  if(1 in _word.split(key_)){
   return _filter[key_]
  }
 }
 return _word
}

function controlWords(_string, _filter){
 let arr_ = _string.split(" ")
 let length_ = arr_.length
 for(let i_ = 0; i_ < length_; i_++){
  arr_[i_] = reWord(arr_[i_], _filter)
 }
 return arr_.join(" ")
}

string = controlWords(string, cenzrBlock)
console.log(string)
```